# Django: Console returns "value must be a decimal number" on a CharField defined field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Right..... so I'm confused about this. The code function that this error was based on is that a user submits a csv file full of specified data. Django would handle the data processing and add the submitted data to a MySQL database. In the midst of debugging some processing errors, and ensuring that all my defined lists match up with the csv file header order and all, Django's Model.save() function wouldn't work. And so I had exceptions turned on and printed to console, where I get this as the error:

EDIT: Updating this value to the real error result value:

```
[u"'F1216-07a' value must be a decimal number."]
```

Where 'value1' is the data value to be entered into a CharField defined field. Both my models.py file is defined as string, and MySQL database table via PHPMyAdmin has this field defined as char(N). I guess here is the model definition of the field as reference:

```
x_version = models.CharField(choices=X_VERSION_CHOICES, max_length=32, blank=True, verbose_name='By X Field Version')
```

And here is an sample definition of the choices:

```
X_VERSION_CHOICES = (
    ('value1', 'value1'),
    ('value2', 'value2'),
)
```

The values for this field must be one of the pre-defined string choices, so there isn't any option of changing this value to a Decimal value. Why would Django show this error, when the defined type is correct? Would it be because of how the choices constants are defined as?

EDIT: I thought it was self-explanatory question, but here is a code sample of where the model.Save() method crashes at.

```
try:
     ....

     # Value in this reconciliation_required db field must be set as
     # "1" for true, which in test file it is.
     if contracts[line['contract_no']].reconciliation_required:

            # pass SampleDesignParameters the parameter dictionary and 
            # create line_parameters
            line_parameters = SampleDesignParameters(**para_dict)
            line_parameters.contract = contracts[line['contract_no']]
            line_parameters.name = 'Auto-Created'
            line_parameters.save()
            line_sample.parameters = line_parameters

 except Exception as e:
     print e
     # .... more code that generates warnings here
```

Where para_dict is a dictionary with keys as the database named fields, and its values are the data the user enters in for that field. I have printed the dict on console, so for the key & data fields they all line up accordingly. And as for the model itself, its...

```
class SampleDesignParameters(DesignParameters):
    parent_template = models.ForeignKey('DesignParameters', related_name='parent', blank=True, null=True)

...

class DesignParameters(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ....

    # This field that Django has errors saving on:
    f1216_version = models.CharField(choices=F1216_VERSION_CHOICES, max_length=32, blank=True, verbose_name='BY ASTM F1216 VERSION')

....
```

And the proper constants for that field, which are pretty much in the same format as the dummy one:

```
F1216_VERSION_CHOICES = (
    ('F1216-07a', 'F1216-07a'),
    ('F1216-09', 'F1216-09'),
)
```

Comment: Do you have unmigrated changes

Comment: @bryan60 Hmm.... I do since I had to re-add in existing code to version control recently, but that particular field was already migrated and the function was working well on a previous version of it. Might have to check that out though.

Comment: @bryan60 Just applied all unmigrated changes. The same situation still happens.

Comment: please share the code where you call `save()` method, as well as your complete definition of your model and the complete traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that somehow that value is being saved into the wrong field of the model.  Can you catch the error and check the values?  Or maybe there is a likely field, and possibly a bad row in the CSV with a value missing so they are shifted.